# android startactivity from jar by DexClassLoader

Tags: android, dex, dexclassloader

I put the jar file into the sd card, jar files have been processed by dx. In the jar inside a activity, how to start activity in the jar file?

Comment: or can i set jar to the classpath in android at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

You don't, as the activity in the JAR file does not have a manifest entry.